# creating and exporting a csv from Display tag table

Tags: jsp-tags

export is not working for csv:

(org.displaytag.decorator.MessageFormatColumnDecorator:66 - decorate) ==> Caught an illegal argument exception while trying to format an object with pattern {0,date,dd-MMM-yyyy}, returning the unformatted value. Object class is {0,date,dd-MMM-yyyy}

exception is :(org.displaytag.decorator.MessageFormatColumnDecorator:66 - decorate) ==> Caught an illegal argument exception while trying to format an object with pattern {0,date,dd-MMM-yyyy}, returning the unformatted value. Object class is {0,date,dd-MMM-yyyy}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you don't have `escapeXml="true"` as a property for your `display:column` tag.

I know it's probably too late for the OP to get this answer, but I think this could help some people stuck with this problem.